# Google Search Results Hijacking in OS X

Tags: macos, browser, safari

I'm noticing an occasional browser hijack for search results when I first click on a session in Google Search.  I'm taken to a website not intended that's only in an ip address format that's another type of keyword search site.  The really odd thing is that it doesn't happen frequently enough to guess when I'll be hijacked again.  It doesn't seem to do anything negative to my system other than the fact that I have to manually go back to google.com and click again to get to what I wanted.

I only see this on my OS X system, which is up to date, but held back to 10.5.8

I haven't noticed this on my Windows 7 laptop.

I've googled around and find people with this problem, but not independently for an OS, like on OS X for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be connected to me running a java application on my computer (which may have been malcoded).  Once uninstalled, I haven't noticed any more hijacks of search results, and this is one of the only changes to my system in some time.